# Removing more than one view from NavigationStack is not animated

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationstack

I noticed that removing more than 1 view from a NavigationStack (using `.removeLast(k)` on its NavigationPath, where k > 1) is not animated at all. I was expecting to see the previous view sliding right, revealing to root view.. but what I get instead is the previous view disappearing without any animation whatsoever. (however, the animation plays as expected when removing only 1 view from the stack (k = 1))

In the example below, the animation plays when the reset button is tapped from page 2, but it does *not* from page 3, 4 and so on

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var path = NavigationPath()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationStack(path: $path) {
                Subview()
                    .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { n in
                        Subview(n:n)
                    }
            }
            // reset button
            Button(action: onTap) {
                Text("RESET")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
    }
    
    func onTap() {
        if !path.isEmpty {
            let n = path.count
            path.removeLast(n)
        }
    }
}

struct Subview: View {
    var n: Int = 1
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(value: n+1) {
            Text("go to page \(n+1)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```